# Why the character/s or the parent object of the characters never detecting a collision with the door?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot of the door.
The child Horizontal_Doors_Kit have a Box Collider component attached.

[image: Door]

And this is the characters. A female in the front with two soldiers a bit behind.

The whole group the female and the two soldiers are moving and walking using HumanoidWalk and the door in in lock state so they should not pass through the door.

If it's unlocked the door should be open.
But what it does now they are just walking through the door like the door is not exist.

If I will move my player character through the door it will not walk through or will when the door is open. My player character have a capsule collider and a rigidbody.

But since this group of 3 is part of a cutscene I don't need or want to use a rigidbody I think. But I do want that the door will open or not when they collide.

I added to the female character a capsule collider Is Trigger is off. Same like in my player character:

[image: characters]

Maybe I have to add a rigidbody to the leading female character ?

Comment: I tried to add a rigidBody to the character instead the capsule collider. And set to true the is kinematic. But still not working. The character is walking through the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your rigidbody to kinematic, passing through the door is the expected behaviour. If you are using rigidbody physics, leave it as non-kinematic. If you are moving the player yourself, you need to observe collisions (try ontriggerenter and oncollisionenter) yourself, and stop moving after the collision with the door occurs